# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el formato de fecha 'YYYY' y 'RRRR' en Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Subiendo una data a la bd con la que trabajo, me di cuenta que por defecto al colocar un campo del tipo fecha **SQL Developer**  lo coloca en formato 'RRRR' como en la siguiente captura:
[image: Formato de Fecha]

Pero el formato se puede cambiar en la lista a 'YYYY' [image: formato yyyy]

Entonces realicé una consulta para saber que retorna el formato 'RRRR'

```
select to_date(sysdate, 'dd/mm/rrrr') from dual;  /* retorna 17/11/20 */


select to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/rrrr') from dual;  /* retorna 17/11/2020 */
```

Lo que me retorna ese formato 'RRRR' es igual a lo que retorna la consulta con el formato 'YYYY'

```
select to_date(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;  /* retorna 17/11/20 */


select to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;  /* retorna 17/11/2020 */
```

Me gustaría saber si en realidad existe alguna diferencia entre ambos formatos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`YYYY` da el año actual, en formato de 4 digitos.

`RRRR` significa que los años de 2 dígitos en el rango de `00` a `49` se suponen en el siglo actual (es decir, tienen los mismos dos primeros dígitos que el año actual) y los años dados de `50` a `99` en el siglo anterior.

---

Ejemplos:

```
SELECT 
TO_DATE ('010199', 'MMDDYYYY') AS date_a, 
TO_DATE ('010199', 'MMDDYY') AS date_b, 
TO_DATE ('010199', 'MMDDRR') AS date_c, 
TO_DATE ('010199', 'MMDDRRRR') AS date_d 
FROM DUAL;
```

Resultados:

```
DATE_A - 1/1/0099
DATE_B - 1/1/2099
DATE_C - 1/1/1999
DATE_D - 1/1/1999
```

Comment: Interesante la explicación, aunque el ejemplo de date_b en sql developer no me da 2099 como año supongo que debe ser por algo en el formato de la fecha del programa como tal

Comment: Eso estaba revisando, por que saque los ejemplos de otro lado, pero estoy intentando corroborarlos

Comment: Listo si era el formato de la fecha en el sql developer, lo cambié y si aparece el 2099

Comment: Perfecto !!!!! :)

Comment: Gracias por la explicación :D!